# Изучение Angular.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Всем привет.
Имею знания в JavaScript база...
Сел за изучение Angular...
Скачал две книги(объяснение ужасное)...
Кто может дать ссылку на хороший материал? Желательно с нормальным объяснением синтаксиса, так как из того что я вижу, в этом фреймворке изменение было огромное и много происходит "за кулисами" видимого кода...
Для хорошего понимания нужно объяснение таких процессов...

Comment: читайте документацию на сайте ангуляра. А что за синтаксис имеется ввиду?

Comment: Синтаксис ангуляра.. Всё имеется ввиду..

Comment: эм, что за синтаксис ангуляра? у него же две части: код - где обычный `javascript`, и разметка, где обычный `html` - никакого особого синтаксиса нет

Comment: Ты можешь кроме документации дать материал который нормально преподносит объяснение функционала ?  
"никакого особого синтаксиса нет" - даже незнаю че сказать.. как по мне то есть..

Comment: А что не так с документацией? Тем более там есть tutorial?

Comment: @ Grundy - https://habrahabr.ru/post/179755/

Comment: Офф доку читай там вроде все подробно и с картинками цветными

Comment: @Maks.Burkov эта статья трехлетней давности. Сейчас документация вполне ничего. Я сам недавно работал с ангуляром. Единственное - она на английском. Читайте документацию - там примеры рабочие по ходу во фреймах + исходный код. И задавайте более конкретные вопросы тут, если что будет непонятно.

Comment: Читайте сразу про Angular 2, он намного проще и логичнее.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Возможные варианты:

1. [Документация на английском.](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/introduction)
2. [Перевод документации на русский](http://angular-doc.herokuapp.com/guide/overview). Тут информация не столь полна, как в оригинальном источнике, но если с английским плохо, то может пригодиться весьма.
3. Статьи на хабре и прочих сайтах, которые можно легко найти через поиск.

Разумеется предпочтительней первый вариант (можно начать не с него, но с ним все же желательно сверяться по ходу жизни).

Comment: Спасибо. 
Начал изучать Java Script из за проекта который требуют по учебе, 
После определенного углубления по не воле начало появлятся отврашение к языку, и еше больше желание специализироватся в Java,Java EE, C++, надеюсь всё скоро закончится)).

Comment: @Maks.Burkov  Пожалуйста. Я и сам был не в восторге от AngularJS сначала, хотя уже имел опыт на чистом JS и jQuery. Даже могу сказать мне очень нравится JS - простой и в то же время очень хитрый язык, но в контексте AngularJS он приобретает совсем иной колорит. Думаю некоторое отвращение, как это часто бывает, связано не с самим языком, а с тем, что вы не понимаете зачем все это нужно, но вам это "надо" по заданию - в этом проблема многих учебных проектов. Остается лишь пожелать вам терпения))

Comment: При изучении JS,Jquery, както не было такого как с Angular.. жесть..